# In Gerrit, how can we comment on a binary file?

Tags: gerrit

In Gerrit, we can make comments attached to specific lines of a text file, but also a file-level comment about the entire file.

In the diff view, which of course shows no content for a binary file, I do not see any UI for adding a file comment.

Is there some alternative way to do that?

Could it be done through the [Set Review](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#set-review) API, for instance, using `curl`? How?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add a comment in the file running the following command:

```
curl --request POST --user USER:PASS --data @- --header Content-Type:application/json GERRIT-SERVER/changes/CHANGE-ID/revisions/current/review <<EOF
{
    "comments": {
        "FILE-FULL-PATH": [
            {
                "message": "COMMENT"
            }
        ]
    }
}
EOF
```

But it'll not possible to see the comment in the diff view, only in the change log or in the comment thread (down in the change page).